# How different can $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ be?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

Given $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how "different" can $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ be?

By "how different" I mean:

Given two real-valued functions $a,b$ do there exist two real-valued functions $f,g$ such that $f(g(x))=a(x)$ and $g(f(x))= b(x)$?

If not, is there some sens in which $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ can't be "too different"?

Comment: How about starting by seeing if $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$ can be related by some $a,b$?

Comment: @Cheer in your example $f(g)=g(f)$, so it's not clear to me what relation there is supposed to be between $a(b)=f$ and $b(a)=g$ on the one hand, and how different $f(g)$ and $g(f)$ are on the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The OP has unfortunately reused lettering in an inconsistent manner, in the leadup as what is being composed, and in the later block as the results of the compositions.  I'll edit so that it remains consistent.  After the rewording, Cheer's example becomes letting $a=0$ and $b=\text{Id}$

Comment: @JMo Cheer's example is fine, it's Tanny's question I don't get. Why would there be a relation between "$a(b)=f$ and $b(a)=g$" and how different $f(g)$ and $g(f)$ are?

Comment: @GerryMyerson that should be cleared up with the rewording.  The question is "can we find functions such that their compositions with one another can be as different as we like?"  I.e. can we find functions such that their composition in one direction is an arbitrary preselected result while the composition in the other direction is some other arbitrary result.  Your using both $a(b)$ and $f(g)$ in the same sentence implies that you might still be confused even after my edit.  With the edit, $a(b)$ is not being considered at all.  $a$ is exclusively the result of one of the compositions.

Comment: Consider the identity function $\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R}$ and some constant function $c$. Assume for a contradiction that there are suitable $f,g$ satisfying $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R}$ and $g \circ f = c$.

Then $c = c \circ g = (g \circ f) \circ g = g \circ (f \circ g) = g$, so $g$ is constant, and therefore $f \circ g$ is also constant. But then $f \circ g \neq \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the particular case both $a$, $b$ are bijective. If $f$, $g$ exist, they must also be bijective. But that means 
$$b = g (fg)g^{-1}=g a g^{-1}$$
that is, $b$ is conjugate to $a$.   Conversely, if 
$$b = g a g^{-1}$$ then $a = a g^{-1} g$ and $b= g(a g^{-1})$.

So now you can investigate a similar problem: when two functions $a$, $b$ are conjugated under a bijection. This happens if and only if they oriented graphs given by these maps are isomorphic. If $a$, $b$ are bijections that means if and only if they have the same cycle structure.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f$ and $g$ do not always exist.

Indeed, suppose that $a$ and $b$ are two bijections that have different orders in the group of all bijections from the set of real numbers to itself. Then, since $f \circ g=a$ and $g \circ f=b$ are bijective, so are $f$ and $g$. But then $a$ and $b$ would be conjugate, a contradiction since they have different orders and conjugate elements in any group always have the same order.

For example, consider the involution $x \mapsto -x$ and the map $x \mapsto x+1$. The former has order two, while the latter has infinite order. Also, there do not exist any two functions $f$ and $g$ for which $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (f(g(x))=-x) \land (g(f(x))=x+1)$, for we would then have $f(g(f(x)))$ equal to both $f(x+1)$ and $-f(x)$ for any real number $x$, and then $f(x+2)=-f(x+1)=-(-f(x))=f(x)$ and $g(f(x))=g(f(x+2))=x+3 \neq x+1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Given some function $h(x),$ let $f(x)$ be the function $h$ iterated $m$ times, and $g(x)$ be $h$ iterated $n$ times. So, these commute.

This is how Irvine Noel Baker (1932-2001) modified the study of fractional iteration, the beginning is formal power series commuting with each other.